# Retrieving data from parse in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I am retrieving data in `data`. This is my code..
        `var data:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()`

```
func loadData() {

    data.removeAllObjects()

    var findData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Sweets")
    findData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            println(error)

        } else if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {

                self.data.addObject(object)

            }

            var array:NSArray = self.data.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.data = array as! NSMutableArray // Getting error here.. Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10391c420) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x10391c4e8).

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }


    }


}
```

please somebody help me.. i m stuck here and i am beginner .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do casting in proper way like as follows :

```
var findData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Sweets")
findData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        println(error)
    } else if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {
            self.data.addObject(object)
        }
        var array:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: self.data.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects)
        self.data = array as NSMutableArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```